# Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify that your system recognizes them, and run this command again

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, nativescript, nativescript-vue, android-sdk-manager

Edit: `tns run android` works on android-studio ide but not on vscode. I got it running in android-studio by clicking the `configure` in the picture below:

[image]

I'm new to nativescript and android studio scene and configuring things out is really a hell of an experience, I got this existing project that I got running yesterday and when I try to run it again today with `tns run android` it now don't see the emulator that I have installed and the same emulator it used to run just yesterday. Here are the details of my config:

Installed Packages:
[image]

Path and Environment configuration:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now if I run `tns device android --available-devices` this show up:
[image]
And it still insist that it cannot find any devices when it just found one!

Running `tns-devices` can't find it as well:
[image]

It also says All is good when I run `tns doctor`:
[image]

So my question would be, what am I missing here? Is it a missing package? Is it a wrong android configuration? Do I have to reinstall android studio from the start (Already did this twice!)

Comment: Your emulator is showing in your available devices.  What happens when you run `tns run android --device Pixel_4a_API_30`?

Comment: You can also try `tns run android --emulator`.

Comment: @JasonWhite thanks for taking your time to answer, I just had to restart my unit and open the emulator on android studio, after that I ran `tns run android` on vs code and it ran perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me:

1. restarted my unit.
2. ran the emulator from android studio.
3. ran `tns run android` on vscode.

and it just worked. Also, [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3044#issuecomment-322984593) might help you as well.